# Best practices to define intents in dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am working on dialogflow for the first time. Can somebody suggest best practices in defining the intents? Also is it a good practice to define a single intent which covers a wide range of user queries or create different intents for different set of questions?

Comment: The best practice IMO is to create a single intent with a wide variety of user query. IN your case of different intents, you should design the conversation flow with context and followup which can create a hassle instead of help.

Comment: can you suggest some elaborated explanation or some online resources where i can refer and develop a better flow. @nikhilesh_koshti

Answer (score 3):

A good starting point are the following articles about how Google created the I/O 2018 AoG:

[Part 1: How we designed it: the Google I/O ’18 Action for the Google Assistant](https://medium.com/google-developers/how-we-designed-it-the-google-i-o-18-action-for-the-google-assistant-9370ffbaf9b0)

[Part 2 (Dialogflow part): How we built it: the Google I/O ’18 Action for the Google Assistant](https://medium.com/google-developers/how-we-built-it-the-google-i-o-18-action-for-the-google-assistant-7f287ad31b7)

Best

Alex

Answer (score 2):

As with everything: "it depends".

Mostly I keep in mind that an Intent represents the user trying to express something to you. If those questions are similar, and can easily be represented by different questions with parameters that you handle roughly the same on the back end - then by all means, have it as a single Intent.

Examples of this might be

- Do you have vanilla ice cream?
- Is chocolate for sale?
- Can I get cookies and cream?

which are all asking if something is available, but varying on what that something is.

But you may also have questions that fundamentally differ from each other, and these should each be done as different Intents. For example

- Where are you located?
- What time are you open? (Although variants such as "Are you currently open?" and "What time do you close?" might all be the same Intent.)

These are different types of questions and your users expect different responses from them.